# VB.NET exe : (name) has stopped working

Tags: vb.net

I made a .exe using VB.NET 3.0 (and visual studio). It works just fine, but on termination, I get a windows error:

> "(program name) has stopped working."

, instead of it just closing silently. 
I put a msgbox the line before the "`end sub`" of "`sub main`" and it does show up, thus proving I arrive there without an error.
==> why do I get this message? Maybe I forgot to use an object Finalize?

It's not actually a big deal (it works anyway), but releasing an .exe that acts this way may raise questions from the users...

Comment: Did you try to debug and see from console/output window if it captures anything?

Comment: If I launch it from CMD, it gives no feedback. Would you explain how to do the other tests? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the call stack? It seems like there could be an infinite loop or another call that hasn't been terminated within your code

Comment: @David : nope, the code is fully ended (successfully), I reached the "end sub" and I removed any multithreading to make sure no thread was still working

Comment: Bit of a bodge but in the situation i'd put a try catch block around the whole code and then do messagebox.show(x.message) to see what's going on when the crash happens

Comment: @Shovers_ : I tried a "try... catch" ==> I never get to catch. There is no error in the code... like the program terminates without telling windows that it did rightfully, then windows assumes there was an error

Comment: in that case the application or system logs in the windows event viewer might give some indication as to why it crashed. In the source column the error should appears as .NE Runtime - it may give you a stack trace in there

Comment: @Shovers_ : i'm not admin on my computer, and I cannot access it...  :-(

Comment: Try subscribing to the [**`AppDomain.UnhandledException` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) and log the message from `DirectCast(e.ExceptionObject, Exception).Message`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was : one of the class finalize was not protected enough and did raise an error.
Thanks all for your help.